# Base 64 Encoding very long string Java Overflow, Arduino Energia IDE, TI CC3200

Tags: java, regex, base64, overflow, arduino-ide

Hello some issues with this I have looked into it, someone said it is a RegEx error with Java but I didn't even think Energia was using Java... bit confused on why this error is popping up with C code.

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
```

...and it goes on hundreds of more lines of the same stuff.

As for the regex code:

Note that in this case I hard-coded in the section for my image (this is the field causing the error) just for testing purposes, I want to transmit the JSON message with base64 encoding over the network to a web service which will relay it to my email as a picture.

If the image string is shortened then no error occurs but of course this is much too small of a string to transmit an actual picture. Really appreciate your help!

```
// [7.12.2] Class template regex_token_iterator
  /**
   * Iterates over submatches in a range (or @a splits a text string).
   *
   * The purpose of this iterator is to enumerate all, or all specified,
   * matches of a regular expression within a text range.  The dereferenced
   * value of an iterator of this class is a std::tr1::sub_match object.
   */
  template<typename _Bi_iter,
       typename _Ch_type = typename iterator_traits<_Bi_iter>::value_type,
       typename _Rx_traits = regex_traits<_Ch_type> >
    class regex_token_iterator
    {
    public:
      typedef basic_regex<_Ch_type, _Rx_traits> regex_type;
      typedef sub_match<_Bi_iter>               value_type;
      typedef std::ptrdiff_t                    difference_type;
      typedef const value_type*                 pointer;
      typedef const value_type&                 reference;
      typedef std::forward_iterator_tag         iterator_category;

    public:
      /**
       * @brief Default constructs a %regex_token_iterator.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       * 
       * A default-constructed %regex_token_iterator is a singular iterator
       * that will compare equal to the one-past-the-end value for any
       * iterator of the same type.
       */
      regex_token_iterator();

      /**
       * Constructs a %regex_token_iterator...
       * @param a          [IN] The start of the text to search.
       * @param b          [IN] One-past-the-end of the text to search.
       * @param re         [IN] The regular expression to search for.
       * @param submatch   [IN] Which submatch to return.  There are some
       *                        special values for this parameter:
       *                        - -1 each enumerated subexpression does NOT
       *                          match the regular expression (aka field
       *                          splitting)
       *                        - 0 the entire string matching the
       *                          subexpression is returned for each match
       *                          within the text.
       *                        - >0 enumerates only the indicated
       *                          subexpression from a match within the text.
       * @param m          [IN] Policy flags for match rules.
       *
       * @todo Implement this function.
       * @doctodo
       */
      regex_token_iterator(_Bi_iter __a, _Bi_iter __b, const regex_type& __re,
               int __submatch = 0,
               regex_constants::match_flag_type __m
               = regex_constants::match_default);

      /**
       * Constructs a %regex_token_iterator...
       * @param a          [IN] The start of the text to search.
       * @param b          [IN] One-past-the-end of the text to search.
       * @param re         [IN] The regular expression to search for.
       * @param submatches [IN] A list of subexpressions to return for each
       *                        regular expression match within the text.
       * @param m          [IN] Policy flags for match rules.
       *
       * @todo Implement this function.
       * @doctodo
       */
      regex_token_iterator(_Bi_iter __a, _Bi_iter __b,
               const regex_type& __re,
               const std::vector<int>& __submatches,
               regex_constants::match_flag_type __m
                 = regex_constants::match_default);

      /**
       * Constructs a %regex_token_iterator...
       * @param a          [IN] The start of the text to search.
       * @param b          [IN] One-past-the-end of the text to search.
       * @param re         [IN] The regular expression to search for.
       * @param submatches [IN] A list of subexpressions to return for each
       *                        regular expression match within the text.
       * @param m          [IN] Policy flags for match rules.

       * @todo Implement this function.
       * @doctodo
       */
      template<std::size_t _Nm>
        regex_token_iterator(_Bi_iter __a, _Bi_iter __b,
                 const regex_type& __re,
                 const int (&__submatches)[_Nm],
                 regex_constants::match_flag_type __m
                 = regex_constants::match_default);

      /**
       * @brief Copy constructs a %regex_token_iterator.
       * @param rhs [IN] A %regex_token_iterator to copy.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      regex_token_iterator(const regex_token_iterator& __rhs);

      /**
       * @brief Assigns a %regex_token_iterator to another.
       * @param rhs [IN] A %regex_token_iterator to copy.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      regex_token_iterator&
      operator=(const regex_token_iterator& __rhs);

      /**
       * @brief Compares a %regex_token_iterator to another for equality.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      bool
      operator==(const regex_token_iterator& __rhs);

      /**
       * @brief Compares a %regex_token_iterator to another for inequality.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      bool
      operator!=(const regex_token_iterator& __rhs);

      /**
       * @brief Dereferences a %regex_token_iterator.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      const value_type&
      operator*();

      /**
       * @brief Selects a %regex_token_iterator member.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      const value_type*
      operator->();

      /**
       * @brief Increments a %regex_token_iterator.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      regex_token_iterator&
      operator++();

      /**
       * @brief Postincrements a %regex_token_iterator.
       * @todo Implement this function.
       */
      regex_token_iterator
      operator++(int);

    private: // data members for exposition only:
      typedef regex_iterator<_Bi_iter, _Ch_type, _Rx_traits> position_iterator;

      position_iterator __position;
      const value_type* __result;
      value_type        __suffix;
      std::size_t       __n;
      std::vector<int>  __subs;
    };

  /** @brief Token iterator for C-style NULL-terminated strings. */
  typedef regex_token_iterator<const char*>             cregex_token_iterator;
  /** @brief Token iterator for standard strings. */
  typedef regex_token_iterator<string::const_iterator>  sregex_token_iterator;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
  /** @brief Token iterator for C-style NULL-terminated wide strings. */
  typedef regex_token_iterator<const wchar_t*>          wcregex_token_iterator;
  /** @brief Token iterator for standard wide-character strings. */
  typedef regex_token_iterator<wstring::const_iterator> wsregex_token_iterator;
#endif
```

base64.c:

```
#include <string.h>

#include "base64.h"

/* aaaack but it's fast and const should make it shared text page. */
static const unsigned char pr2six[256] =
{
    /* ASCII table */
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};

int Base64decode_len(const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);

    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    return nbytesdecoded + 1;
}

int Base64decode(char *bufplain, const char *bufcoded)
{
    int nbytesdecoded;
    register const unsigned char *bufin;
    register unsigned char *bufout;
    register int nprbytes;

    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;
    while (pr2six[*(bufin++)] <= 63);
    nprbytes = (bufin - (const unsigned char *) bufcoded) - 1;
    nbytesdecoded = ((nprbytes + 3) / 4) * 3;

    bufout = (unsigned char *) bufplain;
    bufin = (const unsigned char *) bufcoded;

    while (nprbytes > 4) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    bufin += 4;
    nprbytes -= 4;
    }

    /* Note: (nprbytes == 1) would be an error, so just ingore that case */
    if (nprbytes > 1) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[*bufin] << 2 | pr2six[bufin[1]] >> 4);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 2) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[1]] << 4 | pr2six[bufin[2]] >> 2);
    }
    if (nprbytes > 3) {
    *(bufout++) =
        (unsigned char) (pr2six[bufin[2]] << 6 | pr2six[bufin[3]]);
    }

    *(bufout++) = '\0';
    nbytesdecoded -= (4 - nprbytes) & 3;
    return nbytesdecoded;
}

static const char basis_64[] =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int Base64encode_len(int len)
{
    return ((len + 2) / 3 * 4) + 1;
}

int Base64encode(char *encoded, const char *string, int len)
{
    int i;
    char *p;

    p = encoded;
    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
    *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2) |
                    ((int) (string[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
    *p++ = basis_64[string[i + 2] & 0x3F];
    }
    if (i < len) {
    *p++ = basis_64[(string[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
    if (i == (len - 1)) {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4)];
        *p++ = '=';
    }
    else {
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i] & 0x3) << 4) |
                        ((int) (string[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        *p++ = basis_64[((string[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2)];
    }
    *p++ = '=';
    }

    *p++ = '\0';
    return p - encoded;
}
```

base64.h:

```
#ifndef _BASE64_H_
#define _BASE64_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int Base64encode_len(int len);
int Base64encode(char * coded_dst, const char *plain_src,int len_plain_src);

int Base64decode_len(const char * coded_src);
int Base64decode(char * plain_dst, const char *coded_src);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //_BASE64_H_
```

To explain further: This error gets triggered when I try to insert the jpeg image with pre-encoded base64 text... I want to make sure I can transmit a dummy image before I try to instantiate my embedded camera. I'm pretty sure it's not the base64 code but rather the Java Regex which I know nothing about (simply that it deals with tokenizing long strings and seems related to the error). Perhaps it is trying to find a pattern in the string and since it is a very long random string it isn't able to do that and then faults?

Comment: The error is really implying there is an issue with a regex that takes too much "steps" to find a match. Please share this regex.

Comment: Is this error being thrown by the Energia IDE when you try to edit that file?

Comment: The code you've shared is kind of uninteresting - the code needed to help you is in the method `Base64encode`. Can you share the `base64.h`/`base64.c`?

Comment: Wiktor: Where is the regex located? 
Alan: yeah the error is thrown by Energia.
ClasG: Okay I'll post those as well one moment.

Thank you all for the quick responses, this is for a school project due next week and I still need to get my embedded camera functioning as well. Hopefully we can resolve today.

Comment: Made appropriate edits to show regex token iterator function... still not sure if this is culprit. Maybe I can send file over to you Wiktor? It is very long..

Comment: The Energia IDE is written in Processing, which in turn is written in Java, so there's your Java connection.  The regex that's failing is probably part of the syntax highlighting system in the IDE.  If that's the case, it's up to the developers to fix it.  Have you tried their [discussion forum](http://forum.43oh.com/forum/119-energia/)?

Comment: I haven't Alan, I may try that. I'm hoping that my test case is actually not going to replicate the real case, since the camera will output a file which may not need to be parsed in a similar fashion. In any case, editing the RegEx stuff is beyond my capacity for time, so I'll have to find a different workaround. Appreciate the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the IDE token parsing for long strings related to Java regex. May contact their dicussion forum for more info.